# How can I deal with circular references in MobX?

Tags: javascript, mobx

I have this code:

```
var root = {};
var left = {};
rootClass.left = left;
var right = {};
right.left = left;
left.right = right;
var o = observable(root);
```

`right` has pointer to `left` and `left` has pointer to `right`. 
When last line executed I get this error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at _tryDefineProperty (vendor.bundle.js:91185)
    at Function.Object.defineProperty (vendor.bundle.js:91141)
    at addHiddenFinalProp (vendor.bundle.js:14605)
    at asObservableObject (vendor.bundle.js:14122)
    at Function.IObservableFactories.object (vendor.bundle.js:12329)
    at deepEnhancer (vendor.bundle.js:13382)
    at new ObservableValue (vendor.bundle.js:14280)
    at defineObservableProperty (vendor.bundle.js:14163)
    at defineObservablePropertyFromDescriptor (vendor.bundle.js:14143)
    at extendObservableHelper (vendor.bundle.js:12207)
    at extendObservable (vendor.bundle.js:12178)
    at Function.IObservableFactories.object (vendor.bundle.js:12330)
    at deepEnhancer (vendor.bundle.js:13382)
    at new ObservableValue (vendor.bundle.js:14280)
    at defineObservableProperty (vendor.bundle.js:14163)
```

How can I deal with circular references in MobX?

Comment: "How can I deal with circular references in MobX" don't assign two variables to each other?

Comment: It's not assigned by me. I get this model from server.

Comment: then i would re think your structure. maybe creating a parent object that knows about these two objects, and do the logic you want on this parent object.

Comment: good, but not real idea . Data from server contains about 100K lines of json with several circles, used in several clients, part of database model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind MobX is Excel spreadsheets. You need to think about which data can be derived and which could'nt be derived.

References are a great example of derived data, if your object have a circular structure with keys.

Which you'll end up doing is simply store all the objects keyed by id in a object (or a MobX Map).

Next, **instead of creating the left and right properties, create them as computed getters and setters.**

Left and right object id will be stored in properties (e.g. leftId and rightid).

The getter will simply resolve the left or right by looking at the leftId in the root object store. The setter will simply provide a logic to store the id in the leftId/rightId property instead of storing the whole object.

```
observable({
    id: nextId(), // progressive id for sample
    name,
    leftId: null, // variables to store the id in {$ref: 1}
    rightId: null,
    get left(){ // getters and setters
      return allItems.has(this.leftId) ? 
        allItems.get(this.leftId) : 
        null
    },
    set left(item){
      this.leftId = item ? item.id : null
    },
    get right(){
      return allItems.has(this.rightId) ? 
        allItems.get(this.rightId) : 
        null
    },
    set right(item){
      this.rightId = item ? item.id : null
    },
  })
```

**Whole Fiddle Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/4ure5kak/2/